# Openshift Wordpress Service Temporary Unavaliable. Can't restart application

Tags: wordpress, openshift

I'm having a problem on a Wordpress instance I need to show to a client.

I'm using free gear. The app is not intended for production yet. Everything was working fine, I made a child-theme. Have been working on this page for about a month. Since yesterday morning I'm getting: **Service Temporarily Unavailable** when I try to access the page. It isn't the first time this happens, but it never lasted more then a few hours. Now it has been almost 48 hours. I need to show her the demo but I can't make it work.

Here is the output of the tail command:

```
C:\Users\Joao Paulo\Projetos\GibbInsurance\sources\demo>rhc tail demo
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
==> app-root/logs/mysql.log <==
140820 22:03:29 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connec
tions.
Version: '5.5.37'  socket: '/var/lib/openshift/539c92755973caa1f000044c/mysql//s
ocket/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
140823 18:05:36 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown
140823 18:05:36 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
140823 18:05:36  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
140823 18:05:39  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 9866622
140823 18:05:39 [Note] /opt/rh/mysql55/root/usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complet
e
chown: changing ownership of `/var/lib/openshift/539c92755973caa1f000044c/mysql/
/stdout.err': Operation not permitted
140823 18:05:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/539c92755973
caa1f000044c/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended
140823 18:05:39 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/openshift/539c92755973
caa1f000044c/mysql/pid/mysql.pid ended

==> app-root/logs/php.log <==
10.6.135.27 - - [23/Aug/2014:16:10:37 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.6.135.27 - - [23/Aug/2014:16:10:37 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.6.135.27 - - [23/Aug/2014:17:10:38 -0400] "POST /wp-cron.php?doing_wp_cron=14
08828238.7940719127655029296875 HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "WordPress/3.9.2; http://dem
o-gibbinsurance.rhcloud.com"
10.6.135.27 - - [23/Aug/2014:17:10:38 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
10.6.135.27 - - [23/Aug/2014:17:10:39 -0400] "HEAD / HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Ruby"
- - - [23/Aug/2014:17:10:41 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15
 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
- - - [23/Aug/2014:18:05:41 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15
 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
- - - [23/Aug/2014:18:05:41 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15
 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
- - - [23/Aug/2014:18:05:41 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15
 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
[Sat Aug 23 18:05:41 2014] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
Interrupted
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? Y
```

When I try to restart the server, this is what I'm getting:

```
C:\Users\Joao Paulo\Projetos\GibbInsurance\sources\demo>rhc app restart -a demo
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for
/var/lib/openshift/539c92755973caa1f000044c/mysql
Failed to execute: 'control restart' for
/var/lib/openshift/539c92755973caa1f000044c/php
```

I appreciate any help.

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a force-stop on your application, and then a start and see if that helps.  You should also try checking your quota and make sure that you are not out of disk space on your gear.

Comment: Que quota is ok. Just run it and there's 231mb used out of 1 GB.

The app stopped with force stop. But it can't restart.

    
    C:\Users\Joao Paulo\Projetos\GibbInsurance\sources\demo>rhc app start -a demo
    DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
    Failed to execute: 'control start' for
    /var/lib/openshift/539c92755973caa1f000044c/mysql
    Failed to execute: 'control start' for
    /var/lib/openshift/539c92755973caa1f000044c/php